# How to replicate the state of a deployed contract in development environment

Tags: truffle, contract-debugging

I'm trying to debug a contract that has been deployed, and I'd like to have a debug version that has a contract state as close as possible to the version in production (variable values).

The first thing that I noticed is that I don't know how to find the value of this data on https://etherscan.io is there another place to find them?

The second thing is how to I replicate this to my debug environment (let's say truffle/ganache-cli)?

For now I'm importing the JSON of the Etherscan API  and replaying transactions using a truffle script with some way to map test accounts with real accounts, but I'm not sure it's putting me to the correct state.

Any better option?